# Setting up a web project with npm/jQuery/RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I haven't started a new web project for years, so the latest technologies went past me mostly unnoticed...

Now I need to create a little dynamic webpage, for which I mostly need jQuery and maybe one or two plugins. One of them requires a library called RequireJS, which I then had a look at and immediately fell in love with. Javascript just looked so much nicer suddenly! :-)

But... I had also found npm and really like the way of installing new packages. "npm install --save jquery" is just so nice and simple. Now, npm install tons of files in a node_modules sub-directory, which I don't really like. I only need one or two files per library!

So: is there a nicer way than npm to handle packages (i.e. only download the necessary files)? Especially one that works well with RequireJS? Or do I have to set up some other tools (found something called "grunt")? Can someone please give me a working example?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use a build tool like Webpack, Gulp, Grunt, etc to process your assets (minify, concatenate etc) and then deploy the output. You shouldn't deploy the entire `node_modules` as it is. It's not a problem to have it in development phase. BTW if you need a simpler front-end package manager check bower. But it seems NPM is taking over bower.

Comment: Yes, and that's what I need some help with. All resources that I find seem to be for people who know how it works already...